# Icons disappeared from the launcher 12.04

Tags: unity, launcher, compiz, icons

When I start up Ubuntu with Ubuntu desktop, the icons in the launcher becomes invisible as in the image:

[image: Screenshot from launcher]

I can still click & open the applications, but they are just invisible. Icons are shown in dash properly:

[image: Screenshot from dash]

Also, it works properly with Unity 2D option, but its features are restricted for me.

I tried solutions from the web such as:

```
dconf reset -f /org/compiz/
unity --reset 
unity --reset-icons
```

I also reinstalling `ubuntu-desktop`,`compiz`, `unity`, and `ccsm`.

None of them helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is solved by reinstalling and upgrading nvidia driver from `nvidia-304` to `nvidia-340`(somehow it did not work for the first trial).